# How do you register a component in Castle which takes another component as a parameter in code?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

What is the correct way to pass another component into Eq()?

```
_container.Register(
                 Component.For<IDocumentManagementServiceProvider>()
            .ImplementedBy<DocumentumServiceProvider>()
            .Parameters(Parameter.ForKey("credentials").Eq(?) // <---right here
```

Solution:

```
_container.Register(
                Component.For<IDocumentManagementServiceProvider>()
                    .ImplementedBy<DocumentumServiceProvider>()
                    .ServiceOverrides(
                        ServiceOverride.ForKey("credentials").Eq("documentum.repository.credentials"))
                    .DependsOn(Property.ForKey("numberOfTimesToRetryOperation").Eq(2))
                    .DependsOn(Property.ForKey("millisecondsBetweenRetries").Eq(1000))
                    .Named("document.management.service.provider"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windsor will by default auto-wire the first component that is registered with the required interface. If you don't want this behavior, or want a specific component, you can use [service overrides](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Supplying_the_component_for_a_dependency_to_use_Service_override_9).

Also see the "[Registering components](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components.ashx)" page of the Windsor wiki.